# Image in fixed header moves when window resizes

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header on my page, inside the header is an image. Id like it to stay in place when the window is resized.

I have tried different positioning tags and wrapper divs, but i must not be doing something right.

My CSS is as follows

```
.header {
    background: url("#") repeat-x scroll left top transparent;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#headbar {
   position:fixed;
   z-index: 99999;
   left:0px;
   top:0px;
   height:50px;
   width:100%;
   background:#273D90;
   padding-top: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 50px 0;
}

#headbar img {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    left: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*margin: 0 0 0 5%;*/
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
}

.imgwrap{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top:25px;        
}
```

and my HTML is

```
<div class="header">
    <div id="headbar">
        <div class="imgwrap">
            <a href="index.html"><img alt="logo" src="images/whitelogo.png" height="50" width="100"></a>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Try using px instead of % for the image. You have: left: 5%; now.

Comment: Gimmy is correct, because you have left: 5%; it's now considered fluid  this means that as the resolution grows(such as resizing), so will pixel the value the browser assigned to the % value.

Comment: @Gimmy thanks!, now what if i wanted the logo to stay in place relative to the body of the page, IE, page resizes, the body stays centered and i want the logo to be on the left margin on the centered page?

Comment: @BJack if you have any insight as well

Answer (score 1):

Your header is `100%` of the width of the page.  Your image is positioned with `left: 5%`.  That is `5%` of the width of the header.  Since the header resizes when the window does, this `5%` changes.  Use a fixed value with `px` or `em` and it will not move.

http://jsfiddle.net/vfvxE/

Comment: James, be careful, em is a relative unit and can put the context back in a 'relative' positioning.

Comment: @MilchePatern `em` is not relative in the same sense.  `em` is relative to the font-size.  Unless the font-size is changed dynamically, a value in `em` will not change.  It certainly wont' change with the page resizing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I wanted to inform OP about this point, just in case OP is developping something more complex on the @media queries and resizing/scaling the base font-size.

Answer (score 0):

```
#headbar img {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    left: 5%; /*  <--  % is relative */
    overflow: hidden;
    /*margin: 0 0 0 5%;*/
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
}
```

You will have to use **NOT** relatives units to achive what you want. Try using [Absolute lengths units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/): the ‘cm’, ‘mm’, ‘in’, ‘pt’, ‘pc’, ‘px’ units